# How to use ParameterCache with EntLib 5.0

Tags: stored-procedures, enterprise-library

The EntLib 5.0 Developer's Guide says you can use ParameterCache for caching stored procedure parameters, but doesn't give any hints as to how to go about it. Even Googling it didn't provide any answers, and MSDN doesn't seem to have much to say on the matter, either.

Can anyone here provide a sample?

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just happens when you use stored procedures. You don't need to do anything special.

Comment: I stepped into the EntLib code, and it does, in fact, have parameter caching built in! Beautiful! Thank you!